# Azure functions app keeps returning 401 unauthorized

Tags: python, docker, azure-functions

I have created an Azure Function base on a custom image (docker) using VS Code.
I used the deployment feature of VS code to deploy it to azure and everything was fine.

My function.json file specifies anonymous auth level:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why an I still getting the 401 unauthorized error?

Thanks

Amit

Comment: Please give us some more information to enable us to help you. Like: Are you sure you deployed the version with `authLevel` anonymous? Have you tried restarting the Function App? Is Authentication (under Settings) enabled? Are you trying to access the root URL, or an explicit (API) path?

Answer (score 3):

When you make your request to your function, you may need to pass an authorization header with key `'x-functions-key'` and value equal to either your default key for all functions (Function App > App Keys > default in the Azure portal) or a key specific to that function (Function App > Functions > [specific function] > Function Keys > default in Azure Portal).

Answer (score 2):

I changed my authLevel from function to anonymous and it finally worked!

Comment: Please consider providing some source code to support explanation. It helps others to understand the resolution.

Comment: Changing the following binding in functions.json worked for me "authLevel": "anonymous"

Answer (score 0):

Below methods can fix 4XX errors in our function app:

1. Make sure you add all the values from Local.Settings.json file to Application settings (FunctionApp -> Configuration -> Application Settings)
2. Check for CORS in your function app. Try adding “*” and saving it.. reload the function app and try to run it.
   (Any request made against a storage resource when CORS is enabled must either have a valid authorization header or must be made against a public resource.)